# Laravel using map() and return to view + get youtube video ID

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to add the piece of code from [How to get the id of youtube videos in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48559146/how-to-get-the-id-of-youtube-videos-in-laravel) into my Controller.

Error:

> Indirect modification of overloaded property App\Gallery::$link has no
>   effect

GalleryController:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Gallery;

class GalleryController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function galleryAll()
    {

       $gallery = Gallery::orderBy('date', 'desc')
        ->get()
        ->map(function ($gallery) {
            $gallery->link = parse_str( parse_url( $gallery->link, PHP_URL_QUERY ), $gallery->link );
            return view('gallery', ['gallery' => $gallery]);
        });


    }
}
```

I'm unsure on how to save it to the $gallery-link. I'm planning on doing a @foreach in the View, and I want all the $gallery-link to be modified to only contain the youtube video code.

Update:

Controller

```
class GalleryController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function galleryAll()
    {

       return Gallery::orderBy('date', 'desc')
        ->get()
        ->map(function ($gallery) {
            return view('gallery', ['gallery' => $gallery]);
        });


    }
}
```

Page gives me:

> [{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]

Using

```
$gallery = Gallery::orderBy('date', 'desc')
```

gives me blank page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning the view should be the last part of your controller method.

`map()` basically takes the collection, loops through it and allows you to edit each iteration of the loop (each item in the collection) which in your case will be an instance of the `Gallery` model. So, what you're actually doing in you code is replacing each `Gallery` instance with an instance of `Illuminate\View\View` and then returning a collection of that.

As for the "Indirect modification of overloaded property" error you're getting have a look at: [Indirect Modification of Overloaded Property Laravel MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34467076/indirect-modification-of-overloaded-property-laravel-mongodb)

I would suggest using an [Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) for this. In your Gallery model add the following:

```
public function getYoutubeIdAttribute()
{
    parse_str( parse_url( $this->link, PHP_URL_QUERY ), $query);

    return $query['v'];
}
```

Then your controller would just be something like:

```
public function galleryAll()
{
   $gallery =  Gallery::orderBy('date', 'desc')->get();

   return view('gallery', compact('gallery'));
}
```

And finally in your view you can simply access the `youtube_id` like:

```
@foreach($gallery as $g)

    {{ $g->youtube_link }}

@endforeach
```

Comment: I'm confused on where the function getYoutubeIdAttribute() is called. If I call the Gallery::get() in the controller, does it automatically loop through all the functions in the model? Also, you say access it by $g->youtube_link. Where is youtube_link defined? Since we are using $g->link

Comment: "The accessor will automatically be called by Eloquent when attempting to retrieve the value of the first_name attribute:" > So, when a 'function' tries to access a value ($gallery->link), it'll use the 'function'?

Comment: Ahh. I've got it to work: Had to change $gallery->link to $this->link in the model. Thank you!

Comment: The accessor will be available in all of the Gallery models. Also, you won't need to loop through anything in your controller. Laravel uses php's magic methods quite a bit, so when you try and access a value on a model that doesn't exist it will check to see if there is an accessor for that attribute and if so call it.

Comment: Ah, my bad. Sorry about that. I'm glad you got it working!

Answer (score -1):

you can't using:  $gallery->link = parse_str($str,  $gallery->link)

```html
parse_str($str, $output);//output array
because $gallery->link is string
you see:http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php
```

Comment: Still can't get it to work. I think I'm not returning the map/view correctly. When I remove all the code between ->map(function ($gallery) { } except the return view my page is blanco.

Comment: I've updated my question. It actually returns me brackets with no value's.